Delphi XE3 App Loses Oracle 19c (AWS RDS) Connection After VPN Change (Cisco to GlobalProtect)
We have a Delphi XE3 application that connects to an Oracle 19c database hosted on AWS RDS. This has been working fine for 10+ years when users connected via Cisco AnyConnect VPN.
Recently, we switched to Palo Alto Networks GlobalProtect VPN. Since then, the app consistently loses its database session after ~10 minutes.
Here's what we've observed:

Offshore User: An offshore user still on Cisco AnyConnect has no issues with the same app/database.

Consistent Timeout: The 10-minute timeout occurs regardless of the executed stored procedures.

Delphi XE3 Configuration: We use the standard Oracle components (TOracleSession, TOracleQuery, etc.)


Changed SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME to 30 but issue still persisted
